# GET STR sintaxe

Tags: php, json, libcurl

resposta do JSON:

```
      "tipoLogradouro": "AVENIDA",
      "logradouro": "DOIS",
      "numero": "185",
```

PHP para coletar a resposta

```
        $tipolograd= GetStr($data, 'tipoLogradouro":' '",');
        $lograd= GetStr($data, 'lograd":' '",');
        $num= GetStr($data, 'num":' '",');
```

Tenho certeza que estou errando nos "'','"

Alguém pode me dar um exemplo de como seria esse código, corretamente?
Como posso delimitar corretamente a area que preciso pegar neste caso

Comment: 1) não cumprimente ou agradeça nas publicações: Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) 2) Não use as publicações para fazer reclamações, para isso existe o site [META] onde poderá abrir para comunidade uma discussão especifica para a avaliação de sua pergunta.

Comment: 3) Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pegar o corpo de uma requisição com php pode-se utilizar o file_get_contents()

```php
$corpo = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

se o corpo for JSON utiliza-se o json_decode():

```php
$json = json_decode($corpo);
```

então você pode acessar os itens do JSON como um objeto php

```php
echo $json -> tipoLogradouro; // AVENIDA
echo $json -> logradouro;     // DOIS
echo $json -> numero;         // 185
```